# How to break this shape reference code in 2 lines?

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

This code works fine, but i have my sheet BLOCKED for selections.

```
Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("test_" & i).Select
Selection.Formula = ""
```

...and i want to to this:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("test_" & i).Formula = ""
```

But i got the object error to not accept this prop or method.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Formula` is a property of the `DrawingObject` property:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("test_" & i).DrawingObject.Formula = ""
```

For an activeX textbox (assuming you want to change the `LinkedCell` property):

```
Dim tb
Set tb = ActiveSheet.Shapes("test_" & i)
tb.OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell = ""
```

Comment: Still not working.
"Cannot Set Formula Property of TextBox Class"

Comment: What exactly is `"Test_" & i` ?  Not a plain shape?

Comment: I think is a text box.

Comment: Well, it IS a text box.

Comment: Yes. I want to change de LinkedCell but still not working. Same error.
Your code not working, neither this: 
Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("test_" & i).OLEFormat.Object.LinkedCell = ""

Comment: So what kind of "text box" is it?  How was it added to the sheet?

Comment: i went to Insert>Form>TextBox. And its in a group of shapes.

Comment: i dont know what happened but now your DrawingObject answer worked fine. thx

Comment: I was triying to assume (sometimes) "---" to the formula and this is not a valid parameter