# Geting error at TextBoxes property (one codeline)

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I am geting an error at this codeline:

```
BUTTON_PRESSED = 1 'example
var = CInt(Sheets("sheet1").TextBoxes("Title_" & BUTTON_PRESSED).Text)
```

im triying to get the content of the textbox named Title_1

what am i missing?

Comment: Sorry Edited... not that error.

Comment: So what's the error message then?

Comment: Not possible to get Property TextBoxes of Worksheet class

Comment: From your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382527/how-to-break-this-shape-reference-code-in-2-lines), it looks like you are working with an ActiveX textbox - which is not a member of the `TextBoxes` collection.

Comment: same error using var = CInt(Sheets("sheet1").OLEObjects("Title_" & BUTTON_PRESSED).Object.Text)

Comment: `activesheet.oleobjects("Textbox" & 1).object.text` works for me, does `activesheet.oleobjects(1).object.text` work for you?

Comment: No repro with the second line with an ActiveX textbox. Again check naming/spelling.

Comment: same error with both codes

Comment: What workbook is `Sheets("sheet1")` in? Qualify it perhaps. Right now there is an implicit `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: one workbook, one worksheet. its a simple sheet.... any locked contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the text box on your sheet directly, but you can try through the `Shapes` collection.
Use the following:

```
var = CInt(Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("Title_" & BUTTON_PRESSED).DrawingObject.Text)
```

Make sure you have an integer value typed in this textbox.

Comment: Almost!! CInt(Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("Title_" & BUTTON_PRESSED).DrawingObject.Text) not workd, but CInt(Sheets("sheet1").Shapes("Title_1").DrawingObject.Text) worked,.. BUTTON_PRESSED is a simple integer 1... dunno whats happening (sorry i dont know how to mini formating)

Comment: Weird...
If nothing else prevents you from doing it, you can change the assignment to `BUTTON_PRESSED = "1"`.